# JavaScript; Update function by code

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I write (or copy/paste) `<span class="my_class">TEST</span>` in the texarea, `TEST` will appear in text field.

But if I type `TEST` in texarea, mark/activate it and click `Button`, nothing happens in the text field.

Although it's the same input as before when I copy/pasted it.

It seems like the second JS only works it the text is inputed by keyboard and not by JS.

**I have this code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    function my_class(e, t) {
        var n = document.selection ? document.selection.createRange().text : e.value.substring(e.selectionStart, e.selectionEnd);
        if ("" != n) {
            var a = t + n + "</span>";
            e.value = e.value.replace(n, a)
        }
        $('.first').highlightWithinTextarea('update');
    }
    </script>
    
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var n = document.getElementById("first"),
            e = document.getElementById("second");
        n.addEventListener("input", function() {
            var t = [];
            $(n.value).each(function(n, e) {
                "SPAN" == e.nodeName && e.classList.contains("my_class") && t.push($(e).text())
            }), e.value = t.join(" ")
        })
    };
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <input style="font-weight:bold;" class="button" type="button" value="Button" onclick="my_class(first,'<span class=&quot;my_class&quot;>')"><br><br>
    
    <textarea id="first"></textarea><br><br>
    
    <input id="second">
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

What can I do to update my second script when I click the `Button`?

Comment: You have `onkeypress="handleEnterFirstText(event)"` in your html code, but this function is not defined anywhere, so the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: handleEnterFirstText is not defined` is thrown.

Comment: Setting `e.value` does not trigger an event, `input`, `key` and other events are user interaction events. So you would either need to manually trigger an `input` event on the element, call the update function manually.

Comment: @t.niese You're right, just changed it. But this doesn't solve my problem. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is in this line:

```
$('.first').highlightWithinTextarea('update');
```

Remove such a line and add the **highlightWithinTextarea** init in window onload. In any case the selector should be **#first**.

The second issue is: you need to trigger the input event at the end of **my_class** function.

```js
function handleEnterFirstText(e) {

}
function my_class(e, t) {
    var n = document.selection ? document.selection.createRange().text : e.value.substring(e.selectionStart, e.selectionEnd);
    if ("" != n) {
        var a = t + n + "</span>";
        e.value = e.value.replace(n, a);
        if ("createEvent" in document) {
            var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            evt.initEvent("input", false, true);
            document.getElementById("first").dispatchEvent(evt);
        } else {
            document.getElementById("first").fireEvent("oninput");
        }
    }
}
window.onload = function() {
    $('#first').highlightWithinTextarea({
        highlight: 'test'
    });
    var n = document.getElementById("first"),
            e = document.getElementById("second");
    n.addEventListener("input", function() {
        var t = [];
        $(n.value).each(function(n, e) {
            "SPAN" == e.nodeName && e.classList.contains("my_class") && t.push($(e).text())
        }), e.value = t.join(" ")
    })
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/lonekorean/highlight-within-textarea/master/jquery.highlight-within-textarea.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/lonekorean/highlight-within-textarea/master/jquery.highlight-within-textarea.js"></script>

<input style="font-weight:bold;" class="button" type="button" value="Button" onclick="my_class(first,'<span class=&quot;my_class&quot;>')"><br><br>

<textarea id="first" onkeypress="handleEnterFirstText(event)"></textarea><br><br>

<input id="second">
```